# Javascript convert string into function name

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call a JavaScript function name using a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496961/call-a-javascript-function-name-using-a-string)
>   [javascript string to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639837/javascript-string-to-variable)

I have this code:

```
var Functionify = function() {

    return {

        init: function(el, t) {
            var els = document.getElementsByClassName(el);
            var elsL = els.length;

            while(elsL--){
                //els[elsL].onclick = els[elsL].getAttribute(t);
                els[elsL].addEventListener('click', els[elsL].getAttribute(t), false);
            }
        }

    };

}();
```

Where `el = 'myClassName'` and `t = 'data-id'`

Now, 't' is a string, how can tell the addEventListener function to use 't' (a string) as a function name?

Comment: I think you mean to say that `els[elsL].getAttribute(t)` is a string and the name of a variable/function. Otherwise `getAttribute(t)` would not make sense.

Comment: @TheEliteNoob: Good duplicate!

Answer (score 7):

In the global namespace, you would do something like:

```
this.test = function() {
    alert('test');
}

window['test']();
```

The better option however would be to make your function a method of an object you create rather than of the global `window` object.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would do it, put if the function is part of the global scope you can use bracket notation.

```
window["stringName"]();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using eval() is considered "evil", especially in the example given by Danila -- any piece of JS will / can be executed within an eval(). The best option as stated by epascarello, is to use square-bracket notation to invoke a named function. It should be noted, however, that windowt will invoke a function in the global namespace -- if the function is the method of an object, you should reference it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Use eval() function

Example:

```
a = "alert(1)"

eval(a)
```

Comment: this could potentially be dangerous.

Comment: @dqhendricks: (I know you said "potentially", still...) Only if `a` is a string containing JavaScript, received from the server and injected by a malicious user. If you use your own code, it's perfectly fine, although not a very good solution.